# Binary Tree Path Sum (python)

Tags: python, binary-tree

Please check my code. I can't find where is the bug. The question is [here](https://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/binary-tree-path-sum/).

Here is my solution:

```
# Given a binary tree, find all paths that sum of the nodes in the path equals to a given number target.
#
# A valid path is from root node to any of the leaf nodes.

# Example
# Given a binary tree, and target = 5:
#
#      1
#     / \
#    2   4
#   / \
#  2   3
# return
#
# [
#   [1, 2, 2],
#   [1, 4]
# ]



class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    # @param {TreeNode} root the root of binary tree
    # @param {int} target an integer
    # @return {int[][]} all valid paths

    result = []

    def binaryTreePathSum(self, root, target):
        # Write your code here
        if root is None:
            return self.result
        self.dfs(root, [], target)
        return self.result

    def dfs(self, node, tmp, target):
        tmp.append(node.val)
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            if target == sum(tmp):
                #print tmp
                self.result.append(tmp)
            tmp.pop()
            return

        if node.left:
            self.dfs(node.left, tmp, target)
        if node.right:
            self.dfs(node.right, tmp, target)
        tmp.pop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TreeNode(1)
    root.left = TreeNode(2)
    root.left.left = TreeNode(2)
    root.left.right = TreeNode(3)
    root.right = TreeNode(4)
    result = Solution().binaryTreePathSum(root, 5)
    print result
```

Let assume the input is `{1,2,4,2,3}, 5`. After running the solution, the output is `[[],[]]`. But if I unindent the `print tmp`, the output will be

```
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 4]
[[],[]]
```

The output of `tmp` is correct. But it seems that `result.append(tmp)` didn't append the `tmp` into `result`. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: 1. I can't see your "question" because I don't have a lintcode account and I'm not willing to create one. 2. What on earth is `{1,2,4,2,3}`? Is that supposed to be a set? Because if it's a set, it's equal to `{1,2,3,4}`. 3. *"Let assume the input is ..."* The input for _what_? If you pass those parameters to `binaryTreepathSum`, it'll throw an AttributeError.

Comment: Please __post the full code__ (don't let people _guess_ what you're trying to do). Check [\[SO\]: MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway it should be something simple like (sorry for the indent lacking, but it's not possible in comments): `def tree_sum(tree): if tree is None: return 0 else: return tree.val + tree_sum(tree.left) + tree_sum(tree.right)`.

Comment: Sorry for that, I add the full code and the question description.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `result` list contains *one and the same list multiple times*.

You're appending the `tmp` list to `result` like so:

```
self.result.append(tmp)
```

And then you're mutating that very same list with `tmp.pop()` and `tmp.append(...)`. That's why in the end, all your results are empty lists.

The solution is simple, just create a copy of your list:

```
self.result.append(tmp[:])
```

Comment: Cool! This question has troubled me for three hours.  Thank you for getting me out of torture ：）